# Python/OpenCV - Not detecting grid

Tags: python, opencv

The following script comes from http://projectproto.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/opencv-python-2048-game-solver.html

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import win32api, win32gui, win32ui, win32con, win32com.client
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageOps

# create training model based on the given TTF font file
# http://projectproto.blogspot.com/2014/07/opencv-python-digit-recognition.html
def createDigitsModel(fontfile, digitheight):
    font = ImageFont.truetype(fontfile, digitheight)
    samples =  np.empty((0,digitheight*(digitheight/2)))
    responses = []
    for n in range(10):
        pil_im = Image.new("RGB", (digitheight, digitheight*2))
        ImageDraw.Draw(pil_im).text((0, 0), str(n), font=font)
        pil_im = pil_im.crop(pil_im.getbbox())
        pil_im = ImageOps.invert(pil_im)
        #pil_im.save(str(n) + ".png")

        # convert to cv image
        cv_image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array( pil_im ), cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(cv_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
        thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,1,1,11,2)

        roi = cv2.resize(thresh,(digitheight,digitheight/2))
        responses.append( n )
        sample = roi.reshape((1,digitheight*(digitheight/2)))
        samples = np.append(samples,sample,0)

    samples = np.array(samples,np.float32)
    responses = np.array(responses,np.float32)

    model = cv2.KNearest()
    model.train(samples,responses)
    return model

class Board(object):
    UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT = 1, 2, 3, 4
    FONT = "font/ClearSans-Bold.ttf"
    def __init__(self, clientwindowtitle):
        self.hwnd = self.getClientWindow(clientwindowtitle)
        if not self.hwnd:
            return
        self.hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.hwnd)
        self.mfcDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(self.hwndDC)
        self.saveDC = self.mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()

        self.cl, self.ct, right, bot = win32gui.GetClientRect(self.hwnd)
        self.cw, self.ch = right-self.cl, bot-self.ct
        self.cl += win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXSIZEFRAME)
        self.ct += win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYSIZEFRAME)
        self.ct += win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYCAPTION)
        self.ch += win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYSIZEFRAME)*2

        self.saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        self.saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(self.mfcDC, self.cw, self.ch)
        self.saveDC.SelectObject(self.saveBitMap)

        self.tiles, self.tileheight, self.contour = self.findTiles(self.getClientFrame())
        if not len(self.tiles):
            return
        self.digitheight = self.tileheight / 2
        self.digitsmodel = createDigitsModel(self.FONT, self.digitheight)

        self.update()

    def getClientWindow(self, windowtitle):
        toplist, winlist = [], []
        def enum_cb(hwnd, results):
            winlist.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))
        win32gui.EnumWindows(enum_cb, toplist)
        window = [(hwnd, title) for hwnd, title in winlist if windowtitle.lower() in title.lower()]
        if not len(window):
            return 0
        return window[0][0]

    def getClientFrame(self):
        self.saveDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (self.cw, self.ch),
                    self.mfcDC, (self.cl, self.ct), win32con.SRCCOPY)

        bmpinfo = self.saveBitMap.GetInfo()
        bmpstr = self.saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)

        pil_img = Image.frombuffer( 'RGB',
            (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']),
            bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)

        array = np.array( pil_img )
        cvimage = cv2.cvtColor(array, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)
        return cvimage

    def findTiles(self, cvframe):
        tiles, avgh = [], 0

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(cvframe,cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
        thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,1,1,11,2)
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        def findBoard(contours): # get largest square
            ww, sqcnt = 10, None
            for cnt in contours:
                x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
                if w>ww and abs(w-h)<w/10:
                    ww = w
                    sqcnt = cnt
            return sqcnt

        board = findBoard(contours)
        if board==None:
            print 'board not found!'
            return tiles, avgh, board

        bx,by,bw,bh = cv2.boundingRect(board)
        #cv2.rectangle(cvframe,(bx,by),(bx+bw,by+bh),(0,255,0),2)
        #cv2.imshow('board',cvframe)
        #cv2.waitKey(0)
        #cv2.destroyWindow( 'board' )        
        maxh = bh/4
        minh = (maxh*4)/5
        count = 0
        for contour in contours:
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            if y>by and w>minh and w<maxh and h>minh and h<maxh:
                avgh += h
                count += 1
        if not count:
            print 'no tile found!'
            return tiles, avgh, board

        avgh = avgh / count
        margin = (bh-avgh*4)/5
        for row in range(4):
            for col in range(4):
                x0 = bx + avgh*col + margin*(col+1)
                x1 = x0 + avgh
                y0 = by + avgh*row + margin*(row+1)
                y1 = y0 + avgh
                tiles.append([x0, y0, x1, y1])
                #cv2.rectangle(cvframe,(x0,y0),(x1,y1),(0,255,0),2)
        #cv2.imshow('tiles',cvframe)
        #cv2.waitKey(0)
        #cv2.destroyWindow( 'tiles' )       
        return tiles, avgh, board

    def getTileThreshold(self, tileimage):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(tileimage,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        row, col = gray.shape
        tmp = gray.copy().reshape(1, row*col)
        counts = np.bincount(tmp[0])
        sort = np.sort(counts)

        modes, freqs = [], []
        for i in range(len(sort)):
            freq = sort[-1-i]
            if freq < 4:
                break
            mode = np.where(counts==freq)[0][0]
            modes.append(mode)
            freqs.append(freq)

        bg, fg = modes[0], modes[0]
        for i in range(len(modes)):
            fg = modes[i]
            #if abs(bg-fg)>=48:
            if abs(bg-fg)>32 and abs(fg-150)>4: # 150?!
                break
        #print bg, fg
        if bg>fg: # needs dark background ?
            tmp = 255 - tmp
            bg, fg = 255-bg, 255-fg

        tmp = tmp.reshape(row, col)
        ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(tmp,(bg+fg)/2,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)        
        return thresh

    def getTileNumbers(self, cvframe):
        numbers = []
        outframe = np.zeros(cvframe.shape,np.uint8)
        def guessNumber(digits):
            for i in range(1,16):
                nn = 2**i
                ss = str(nn)
                dd = [int(c) for c in ss]
                if set(digits) == set(dd):
                    return nn
            return 0

        for tile in self.tiles:
            x0,y0,x1,y1 = tile
            tileimage = cvframe[y0:y1,x0:x1]
            cv2.rectangle(cvframe,(x0,y0),(x1,y1),(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.rectangle(outframe,(x0,y0),(x1,y1),(0,255,0),1)

            thresh = self.getTileThreshold(tileimage)
            contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

            dh = self.digitheight
            digits = []
            for cnt in contours:
                x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
                if  h>w and h>(dh*1)/5 and h<(dh*6)/5:
                    cv2.rectangle(cvframe,(x0+x,y0+y),(x0+x+w,y0+y+h),(0,0,255),1)
                    roi = thresh[y:y+h,x:x+w]
                    roi = cv2.resize(roi,(dh,dh/2))
                    roi = roi.reshape((1,dh*(dh/2)))
                    roi = np.float32(roi)
                    retval, results, neigh_resp, dists = self.digitsmodel.find_nearest(roi, k=1)
                    digit = int((results[0][0]))
                    string = str(digit)
                    digits.append(digit)
                    cv2.putText(outframe,string,(x0+x,y0+y+h),0,float(h)/24,(0,255,0))

            numbers.append(guessNumber(digits))
        return numbers, outframe

    def getWindowHandle(self):
        return self.hwnd

    def getBoardContour(self):
        return self.contour

    def update(self):
        frame = self.getClientFrame()
        self.tilenumbers, outframe = self.getTileNumbers(frame)
        return self.tilenumbers, frame, outframe

    def copyTileNumbers(self):
        return self.tilenumbers[:]

    def getCell(self, tiles, x, y):
        return tiles[(y*4)+x]

    def setCell(self, tiles, x, y, v):
        tiles[(y*4)+x] = v
        return tiles

    def getCol(self, tiles, x):
        return [self.getCell(tiles, x, i) for i in range(4)]

    def setCol(self, tiles, x, col):
        for i in range(4):
            self.setCell(tiles, x, i, col[i])
        return tiles

    def getLine(self, tiles, y):
        return [self.getCell(tiles, i, y) for i in range(4)]

    def setLine(self, tiles, y, line):
        for i in range(4):
            self.setCell(tiles, i, y, line[i])
        return tiles

    def validMove(self, tilenumbers, direction):
        if direction == self.UP or direction == self.DOWN:
            for x in range(4):
                col = self.getCol(tilenumbers, x)
                for y in range(4):
                    if(y < 4-1 and col[y] == col[y+1] and col[y]!=0):
                        return True
                    if(direction == self.DOWN and y > 0 and col[y] == 0 and col[y-1]!=0):
                        return True
                    if(direction == self.UP and y < 4-1 and col[y] == 0 and col[y+1]!=0):
                        return True
        if direction == self.LEFT or direction == self.RIGHT:
            for y in range(4):
                line = self.getLine(tilenumbers, y)
                for x in range(4):
                    if(x < 4-1 and line[x] == line[x+1] and line[x]!=0):
                        return True
                    if(direction == self.RIGHT and x > 0 and line[x] == 0 and line[x-1]!=0):
                        return True
                    if(direction == self.LEFT and x < 4-1 and line[x] == 0 and line[x+1]!=0):
                        return True
        return False

    def moveTileNumbers(self, tilenumbers, direction):
        def collapseline(line, direction):
            if (direction==self.LEFT or direction==self.UP):
                inc = 1
                rg = xrange(0, 4-1, inc)
            else:
                inc = -1
                rg = xrange(4-1, 0, inc)
            pts = 0
            for i in rg:
                if line[i] == 0:
                    continue
                if line[i] == line[i+inc]:
                    v = line[i]*2
                    line[i] = v
                    line[i+inc] = 0
                    pts += v
            return line, pts
        def moveline(line, directsion):
            nl = [c for c in line if c != 0]
            if directsion==self.UP or directsion==self.LEFT:
                return nl + [0] * (4 - len(nl))
            return [0] * (4 - len(nl)) + nl

        score = 0
        if direction==self.LEFT or direction==self.RIGHT:
            for i in range(4):
                origin = self.getLine(tilenumbers, i)
                line = moveline(origin, direction)
                collapsed, pts = collapseline(line, direction)
                new = moveline(collapsed, direction)
                tilenumbers = self.setLine(tilenumbers, i, new)
                score += pts
        elif direction==self.UP or direction==self.DOWN:
            for i in range(4):
                origin = self.getCol(tilenumbers, i)
                line = moveline(origin, direction)
                collapsed, pts = collapseline(line, direction)
                new = moveline(collapsed, direction)
                tilenumbers = self.setCol(tilenumbers, i, new)
                score += pts

        return score, tilenumbers      

# AI based on "term2048-AI"
# https://github.com/Nicola17/term2048-AI
class AI(object):
    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board

    def nextMove(self):
        tilenumbers = self.board.copyTileNumbers()
        m, s = self.nextMoveRecur(tilenumbers[:],3,3)
        return m

    def nextMoveRecur(self, tilenumbers, depth, maxDepth, base=0.9):
        bestMove, bestScore = 0, -1
        for m in range(1,5):
            if(self.board.validMove(tilenumbers, m)):
                score, newtiles = self.board.moveTileNumbers(tilenumbers[:], m)
                score, critical = self.evaluate(newtiles)
                newtiles = self.board.setCell(newtiles,critical[0],critical[1],2)
                if depth != 0:
                    my_m,my_s = self.nextMoveRecur(newtiles[:],depth-1,maxDepth)
                    score += my_s*pow(base,maxDepth-depth+1)
                if(score > bestScore):
                    bestMove = m
                    bestScore = score

        return bestMove, bestScore

    def evaluate(self, tilenumbers, commonRatio=0.25):

        maxVal = 0.
        criticalTile = (-1, -1)

        for i in range(8):
            linearWeightedVal = 0
            invert = False if i<4 else True
            weight = 1.
            ctile = (-1,-1)

            cond = i%4
            for y in range(4):
                for x in range(4):
                    if cond==0:
                        b_x = 4-1-x if invert else x
                        b_y = y
                    elif cond==1:
                        b_x = x
                        b_y = 4-1-y if invert else y
                    elif cond==2:
                        b_x = 4-1-x if invert else x
                        b_y = 4-1-y
                    elif cond==3:
                        b_x = 4-1-x
                        b_y = 4-1-y if invert else y

                    currVal=self.board.getCell(tilenumbers,b_x,b_y)
                    if(currVal == 0 and ctile == (-1,-1)):
                        ctile = (b_x,b_y)
                    linearWeightedVal += currVal*weight
                    weight *= commonRatio
                invert = not invert

            if linearWeightedVal > maxVal:
                maxVal = linearWeightedVal
                criticalTile = ctile

        return maxVal, criticalTile

    def solveBoard(self, moveinterval=500):
        boardHWND = self.board.getWindowHandle()
        if not boardHWND:
            return False
        bx, by, bw, bh = cv2.boundingRect(self.board.getBoardContour())
        x0, x1, y0, y1 = bx, bx+bw, by, by+bh

        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(boardHWND)
        shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
        print 'Set the focus to the Game Window, and the press this arrow key:'
        keymove = ['UP', 'DOWN', 'LEFT', 'RIGHT']

        delay = moveinterval / 3 # milliseconds delay to cancel board animation effect
        prev_numbers = []
        while True:
            numbers, inframe, outframe = self.board.update()
            if numbers != prev_numbers:
                cv2.waitKey(delay)
                numbers, inframe, outframe = self.board.update()
                if numbers == prev_numbers: # recheck if has changed
                    continue
                prev_numbers = numbers
                move = ai.nextMove()
                if move:
                    key = keymove[move-1]
                    shell.SendKeys('{%s}'%key)
                    print key
                    cv2.waitKey(delay)
                    cv2.imshow('CV copy',inframe[y0:y1,x0:x1])
                    cv2.imshow('CV out', outframe[y0:y1,x0:x1])
            cv2.waitKey(delay)
        cv2.destroyWindow( 'CV copy' )
        cv2.destroyWindow( 'CV out' )


# http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/
# http://ov3y.github.io/2048-AI/
board = Board("2048 - Google Chrome")
#board = Board("2048 - Mozilla Firefox")

ai = AI(board)
ai.solveBoard(360)

print 'stopped.'
```

I have Google Chrome open with the example URL http://ov3y.github.io/2048-AI/ open, running the script has the following error:

```
20.py:109: FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
  if board==None:
no tile found!
Set the focus to the Game Window, and the press this arrow key:
```

Then nothing, it just sits there. So the part I'm concerned with most is `no tile found!`. Un commenting the lines:

```
#cv2.rectangle(cvframe,(bx,by),(bx+bw,by+bh),(0,255,0),2)
#cv2.imshow('board',cvframe)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
#cv2.destroyWindow( 'board' )
```

Shows the following window on screen:

[image]

Can anyone explain why OpenCV is failing to detect the grid, or how to go about debugging this?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it is not a problem with detecting grid, but with capturing browser window - you are trying to find grid on an empty image which of course fails. First make sure that you have grabbed firefox/chrome/opera screen window correctly - in function `getClientFrame(self)` put this code:

```
cv2.imshow('browser window', cvimage)
cv2.waitKey(10000)
```

just before the final `return cvimage`. It should show you the browser window for 10 seconds. If it doesn't than it will 100% sure that problem is with capturing browser window, not with detecting grid. To check what's wrong with capturing browser window use `win32api.GetLastError()` function (you can check error codes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Of course there is a chance that i'm wrong and it's a problem with detecting grid - if so, please provide a sample image (just save the image displayed by the code i provided) so we can test it.

***\\edit:***
I've just noticed the second part of your post - so most likely i'm wrong, but you can test it anyway. It seems that you are capturing one chrome window and part of some other window - try to make your browser window fullscreen.

### ***\\edit2:***

After closer look at you image i realised strange thing - capture image has vertical lines and has width (without  repeated part onthe right side) smaller than the original window(but height seems to be fine). Width seems to be 75% of original width so i guess that PIL treats every 4 bytes as one pixel, but it should use only 3 bytes per pixel. It's hard to test it, because on my system (win 8.1 64bit) it's working fine. Possible solutions (i can't test them, so you need to check which one will work.. sory :) ):

1. Try to change this line:

   ```
       pil_img = Image.frombuffer( 'RGB', (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']), bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)
   ```

   to something like this:
   pil_img = Image.frombuffer( 'RGB', (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']), bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGR', 0, 1)
   generally you need to change value of fifth parameter from `BGRX` to something else - most likely to 'BGR', full list of options is [here](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/concepts.htm#mode). If it won't work try to play with different values of first and fifth parameters.
2. On the screenshot it looks like you have some quite old version of Windows or at least you are using old gui (which is great btw!). If - except for setting gui style to "old style" - you've set (or windows've done it for you) your color quality to something else than "Highest (32bit)" it may cause your problem as well. Try to set it to "Highest (32 bit)". To be clear - i'm talking about settings from this window:
   [image]
   (on the right side, near bottom and color palette).
3. If you have 2 (or more) screens, test you program while using only one. Also if you are using some alternative window manager (or some other weird extension like something for multiple desktops) turn it off and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the window capture displayed is the same as the screenshot above. I've tried Fullscreen & just the grid displaying, Firefox & Chrome. out of curiosity, are you able to run the script successfully and repeat the problem?

Comment: And it still looks like there is part of second window i captured image? 
Try with different browser (you need to change this line: `board = Board("2048 - Google Chrome")`), maybe it's chrome related issue.

Comment: yeah, the CV window is the same size as the Chrome/Firefox window (tried both), but the content of the image it's captured looks squished (note the square grid becomes rectangular) so it looks as though it's getting messed up there.

Comment: To answer your first comment - i'm able to run te script, on my system(win 8.1 x64) capturing browser window is working fine, but it crashes on some font related code. Did edit2 solve you problem?

Comment: Let me take a look at this today, I'll get back to you.

Comment: Bounty was about to expire, thanks for your help so far. The code on the blog actually links to this google code repo: https://code.google.com/p/yus-repo/source/browse/trunk/OpenCV/2048gamesolver/2048opencv.py I'll try your suggestions against this.

Comment: Ok, modify your question and write a comment when you will know something more.